# Programmatically create REST Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I'm trying to build a REST service but the service should not be "static" but dynamically/programmatically created. I'm already aware how to create a REST service with Spring and JAX-RS but do not know how to use it dynamically.

My intention is to create annotations to do some markup on the source code and then use this markup to generate a REST service from it (during launch of the application). The service does not need to change during runtime.

Is it possible to use the possibilities of Spring or JAX-RS during runtime or do I have to completely start from the beginning for example using servlets?

Do you have a suggestion on how to solve the problem. Libraries/Frameworks like Spring or JAX-RS would be prefered.

Comment: Not sure what JAX-RS implementation you are using, but with Jersey (2.x), you can see [Programmatic API for Building Resources](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html)

Comment: This looks like it is exactly what I was looking for. As I'm just starting the development I'm not fixed to one implementation!
Does Spring also offer something like this for it's "REST API"? Could not find it there either.

Comment: I don't know, but integrating Spring with Jersey is not too difficult if you just want to use Jersey for the REST layer and Spring for the rest of the backend layers.

Comment: Ok. That is a good option. Thanks!

Comment: Did you implement this solution? I have a similar requirement and starting out now. So any kind of inputs will be valuable!